# How fetch relationship from CoreData in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I think this is simple but i can't find answer for me. I have two tables. Contacts and messages. Like this:

[image]

And my relationships are in contacts

[image]

And in Messages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXdzl.png)
[image]

I need take SQL: `SELECT contacts.nickName, messages.id, messages.message FROM messages JOIN contacts.ccNumber = messages.senderCcNumber`

My code for now getting a all data from Messages but i don't know how to join table Contacts to this fetch.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Messages")

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "senderCcNumber = %@", argumentArray: ["\(senderID)"] )
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "added", ascending: true)]
do { resultsMessagesList = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) } catch {}
print(resultsMessagesList)
return resultsMessagesList
```

Can someone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData is not a database. You don't need to join any tables (there are no tables).

You shouldn't be storing any foreign keys either.

Once you have a `message` you can get the `contacts` array by using `message.contacts`. You don't need to execute any fetch requests to do this. (Other than to get the message in the first place).

Also, your entities should have singular names (`Contact` not `Contacts`).

If your messages have a sender and a receiver then create two relationships one called `sender` and the other called `receiver` and connect them to the `Contact` entity.

I'd recommend investing in a CoreData basics book. Or there are some very good tutorials online. You would be saving yourself time in learning to use CoreData properly.